# I'm running Percy visual regression testing through the Cypress.IO testing framework but the font in my Percy screenshot aren't correct

Tags: cypress, percy

The fonts are displaying correctly in the Browser but the Percy snapshot is using the incorrect fonts. Not entirely sure what info will help here but here's a snippet of the Cypress + Percy test:

```
describe("Article page", () => {
  it("passes", () => {
    cy.visit("/articles/augustas-story-being-youth-advisor-0");
    cy.document().its("fonts.status").should("equal", "loaded");
    cy.wait(2000);
    cy.percySnapshot();
  });
});
```

And my fonts like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Helvetica LT Std Bold';
  src: url('/themes/custom/planuk/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('/themes/custom/planuk/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
  url('/themes/custom/planuk/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('/themes/custom/planuk/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Bold.svg#HelveticaLTStd-Bold') format('svg');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```